# posix_spawn OSX error sigtrap

Tags: c, macos

Hi i'm just trying to use posix_spawn on OSX , this should work find (as for *nix) anyway after posix_spawn syscall the process will receive SIGTRAP i really cannot uderstand why.

```
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    while(1){
        char *newargv[] = { "/usr/bin/id", 0 };
        char *newenviron[] = {0};
        posix_spawnattr_t  * a;
        posix_spawn_file_actions_t * fa;
        fa = malloc(0x80);
        a = malloc(336);
        //printf("size: %d\n", sizeof(posix_spawnattr_t));
        posix_spawnattr_init(a);
        posix_spawnattr_setflags(a, 0x40);
        posix_spawn_file_actions_init(fa);
        pid_t pid;
        int status = 0;
        posix_spawn(&pid, "/usr/bin/id", fa, a, newargv, newenviron);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("pid: %d\n", pid);
    }
    //printf("pid: %d\n", pid);
    return 0;
}
```

It should run forever but the output from id will be printed just one time.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: No problem under Linux... Sorry, I can't help.

Comment: Take out all the horrible magic numbers that you have hard-coded in and check the return values of all your function calls. Also, why are you mallocing stuff every time around the loop instead of once outside?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are actually trying to do, because you have hard-coded constants and sizes in that may not be relevant on macOS.

The main problem is that your `0x40` flag means that `/usr/bin/id` is exec'ed - just once and replaces the current process so it doesn't go around the loop again!

Other problems should be visible from the version below:

```
#include <spawn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

   char *newargv[] = { "/usr/bin/id", 0 };
   char *newenviron[] = {0};
   posix_spawnattr_t  a;
   posix_spawnattr_init(&a);
   // posix_spawnattr_setflags(&a, 0x40); exec & replace the current process !!!
   pid_t pid;
   int status = 0;
   while(1){
      posix_spawn(&pid, "/usr/bin/id", NULL, &a, newargv, newenviron);
      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      printf("pid: %d\n", pid);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The difference between what you have:

```
posix_spawnattr_t  * a;
a = malloc(336);
```

and what I have:

```
posix_spawnattr_t  a;
```

is that firstly, mine is the correct size no matter how the structure is defined on any particular OS, whereas yours is a hard-coded number that may or may not be correct for any particular OS, and secondly, your method leaks 336 bytes of memory every time through the loop which, given that there is no delay or anything else in the loop, might mean more of a gushing tap/faucet than a minor leak ;-)

Comment: This is supposed to be a site for helping people, not for guessing games. Please state what the "other problems" are.

Comment: @JeremyP I would have thought that working code would be very helpful ! The difference is between declaring `a` thereby ensuring it is the correct size and declaring a pointer to a lump of randomly sized memory that has been malloced using a hard-coded size.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not helpful to have working code - that bit is good, thank you -  I'm saying it is not helpful to say the original code has problems but you are not telling the questioner what they are. If you put the bit about making a the right size in your answer, you'll have my up vote.